# How to remove the Required label in the view page of MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to remove the Required label in the view page of MVC?

I have the Required validator on viewmodel for the field ( Radio Button ).

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
 [Display(Name = "Do you have pain?")]
 public int? IsPain { get; set; }
```

When i try to save without clicking Yes (or) No in the Radio Button, Required validator shows. This is correct.

When i select either Yes (or) No, Required validator should immediately disapper on the view page.

How do i set the visibility immediately to false on the Required validator, after the control selection?

Comment: jQuery?  Hide validation message if an option is selected?

Comment: When you do try to save on first attempt without selecting the controls, we get the Required validator. This is good. Now, when we select either Yes or No, then immediately - Required validator should disable

Comment: The default behavior is the the error message will disappear when you select button. If its not, its due to your code that you have not shown, but an `int?` for a property which should be `bool` makes no sense.